# Do I only have to pay income tax on capital gains?

Tags: canada, capital-gains-tax

In regards to a money lending business - if I lend a person $100 in exchange for $10 (+100), do I pay income tax on $110 or $10? I live in Ontario, Canada.

Comment: I found this question, useful. Thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 1):

On the revenue only. This amount of 10$ will be considered as interest and fully taxable. It will not be a capital gain.

But why would you decide to declare it as an income? 100$ is insignificant. If you lend small amount to friends it cannot be considered a lending business.

Comment: I used that amount for purposes of asking the question. $100 seems like an easy figure to deal with. Only the $10 is taxed?

Comment: You are legally supposed to declare all your income.

Comment: @Jake Your original $100 is not considered income in your example. It's money you started with coming back to you. But the new $10 earned would be considered interest, which is taxed at regular marginal tax rates. The lower capital gain taxes don't apply to money lending situations.